# Python copy-on-write using hardlinks

Tags: python, unix, hardlink

Using Python 2.5+, UNIX:

I have a program which simulates directory "copy-on-write" functionality, by hardlinking all entries. Currently all the underlying code, some of which I don't have access to, uses standard `open(fname, 'w')` to write the regular files.

But with hardlinks, this means the same inode is used (just truncated), so the original content is destroyed as well. For copy-on-write, I would of course want the original to remain untouched (old inode) and the `open('w')` call to create a new inode.

Any ideas on the best way to achieve this? Monkey-patch `open` somehow?

What I came up with so far is overriding `open` to try to delete the file first (if it exists) and only then do `open('w')`:

```
import __builtin__
_open = __builtin__.open

def my_open(name, mode='r', *args, **kwargs):
    """Simulate copy-on-write, by deleting the file first if it exists"""
    if 'w' in mode and os.path.exists(name): # TODO: use isfile()?
        os.remove(name)
    return _open(name, mode, *args, **kwargs)

__builtin__.open = my_open
```

Answer (score 2):

Were you looking for something like this?

```
import sys
old_open = __builtins__.open    

# Override builtin open()
def my_open(fname, *args, **kwargs):
    # If the path is a hardlink, (ie, check that st_nlink >1)
    if os.path.isfile(fname) and os.stat(fname).st_nlink > 1: 
        os.unlink(fname)
    return old_open(fname, *args, **kwargs)
__buitlins__.open = my_open
```

Comment: Yes, except i don't have access to all the libraries that call `open()` internally, and which may be imported in any order, so the solution needs to be more global.

Comment: I see what you mean. changed to override open, then reload all modules.

Comment: @user124114 Ok, that should do the trick and be pretty general.

Comment: The `__builtin__` module is shared globally per process, I don't think the reload is necessary. Anyway, this is the solution I have right now (see the last sentence) :-) I was wondering if there is another, cleverer way -- overriding built-ins is kinda nasty.

Comment: Add `if 'w' in mode and not '+' in mode` ?